# SQL left joing with additional where clause

Tags: mysql, left-join

```
products (products_id, name, type)
orderform (orderform_id, product_id, country_id, price)
```

I want to get all the products that don't exist in the orderform table for a certain country_id.

The following is incorrect and I understand that there a quicker ways, speed is not really an issue just getting the correct result set.

```
SELECT * FROM products p
    left JOIN orderform o ON o.product_id = p.product_id

WHERe o.product_id is NULL AND o.jur_id = 10
```

Thanks guys and gals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p
WHERE product_id NOT IN(SELECT product_id
                        FROM orderform 
                        WHERE jur_id = 10);
```

Also try to move the extra condition to the join condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p
left JOIN orderform o  ON o.product_id = p.product_id
                      AND o.jur_id = 10                        
WHERe o.product_id is NULL;
```

Comment: yep just have to add it to the join condition, i got there ventually. thanks

Answer (score 0):

this one will be simple

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM products p
 WHERE products_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id 
                            FROM orderform
                            WHERE country_id = 10)
```

i cant see `jur_id` in your schema, if you want you can apply that filter too

Answer (score 0):

It will look like this! (not the best approach though)

```
SELECT * FROM products p
left JOIN (select * from orderform WHERe product_id is NULL AND jur_id = 10) o ON o.product_id = p.product_id
```